# Loop through Topic with Adaptive Card

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate, adaptive-cards, power-virtual-agents

I am creating a bot for Microsoft Teams using Power Automate and Power Virtual Agent. I am using an adaptive card as an output where I intend for it to provide an answer and clickable source. I am struggling to find a solution to loop through the source as it is from Power Automate in a list. I have compose it and set it as an output for Power Virtual Agent. Here's what I have worked out so far. `source` has values `link` and `name`.

The idea I had was to do a for loop using the formula method of the adaptive card. Here is my code:

```
{
  type: "AdaptiveCard",
  '$schema': "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  version: "1.0",
  body: [
    {
      type: "TextBlock",
      text: Topic.answer,
      wrap: true
    },
    {
      type: "ActionSet",
      actions: [
        ForAll(ParseJSON(Topic.source).value,{
          type: "Action.OpenUrl",
          title: ThisRecord.Name,
          url: ThisRecord.Link
        })
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, it is only giving the body as an output without the action.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your requirements and share the repro steps so that we can try it from our end.

Comment: Also, here is one sample related to this, please have look into this-https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/4284aa6fbe539451c3f092102f702420f1a4d3be/samples/msgext-unfurling-ac-loop-components/csharp

Comment: Hai! This is something that I intended to have and has been solved. Thanks! https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General/How-to-create-an-adaptive-Card-for-Multiple-options/m-p/1933390/highlight/true#M4733